# Can special constant ::class uses with variables?

Tags: php, class

Can **constant ::class** uses to variable? 
For example `$var::class`, where `$var` class with namespaces.

I tried:

> `$var::class` - error
>
> `${'$var::class'}` - Undefined variable: $var::class in
>
> `eval('$var::class')` - Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of
>   file in : eval()'d code on

My php code:-

```
<?php

namespace Engine\DataBase;


use Logs\Logger;
use Exception;

class DataBaseManager extends DataBaseRequester
{
    const CONTROLLERS = [
        "DataBaseUsersController"
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function complete(string $method, array $params)
    {
        foreach (self::CONTROLLERS as $CONTROLLER) {
            try {
                $class_name = 'Engine\DataBase\\' . $CONTROLLER;
                $method_availability = method_exists(eval('$class_name::class'), $method);
                if ($method_availability) {
                    if (!isset(${$CONTROLLER})) {
                        ${$CONTROLLER} = new $class_name($this);
                    }
                    return ${$CONTROLLER}->$method($params);
                } else throw new Exception("No class with " . $method . " method was found");
            } catch(Exception $e){
                Logger::Log($e->getMessage(), LOGGER::ERROR, "DataBaseManager");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to check in which dynamical (in future) array of class names are needed method without it initialization. 
Current code work if do like hard-code class

```
method_exists(DataBaseUsersController::class, $method);
```

Comment: `$class_name` already stores class name, there's no need to use `::class`.

Comment: @u_mulder yeah, really... so easy)) thanks a lot)

Answer (score 1):

All `::class` does is return a properly constructed string of the fully qualified class name e.g.

```php
namespace SomeNamespace {
    class SomeClass { }
}
namespace {
    $var = SomeNamespace\SomeClass::class;
    echo $var; // SomeNamespace\SomeClass
}
```

You can therefore use a string containing the fully qualified class name as you would use `::class` since the result is the same.

The advantage of using `::class` is that it respects your `use` statements and resolves the fully qualified class name based on them.